# How can I run these two functions at once?

Tags: python, multithreading, animation, ascii, loading

I am trying to make the loading animation show while the text is being printed and when the text is done printing stop the loading animation.

Does anyone have any idea of of how to do this?

```
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread


# This function creates the "animated" text
def delay_print(string):
    for i in string:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(
            0.04
        )


def animated_loading():
    chars = "/—\|"
    
    for char in chars:
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + 'loading ' + char)
        time.sleep(.1)
        sys.stdout.flush()


def text():
    delay_print("\n\nText:\n" + "Hi there,\n\n"
                "{} has something for everyone from {}\n"
                "our airline is currently having a {}% off sale on all {}\n"
                "flights to {}. Book now while seats last!\n\n")


p1 = Thread(target = animation)
p2 = Thread(target = text)

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Comment: Start by fixing the code so that it compiles (what is `animation`? Should it be `animated_loading`?). Your `animated_loading` displays each character once then stops. You should make it run multiple times, or forever. Also both functions print on the same line, you should find a way to fix that too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.